# aws systems manager: Managed instance not appearing in the fleet manager

Tags: aws-ssm

I have created a hybrid activation and then setup an ssm agent on my on-premise windows system.

On my windows on-premise system i can see that the system has been successfully registered as a managed instance with a `MangedInstanceID`

```
PS D:> Get-Content ($env:ProgramData + "\Amazon\SSM\InstanceData\registration")
{"ManagedInstanceID":"mi-xxxxxxxxxx","Region":"us-west-2"}
PS D:>  Get-Service -Name "AmazonSSMAgent"

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  AmazonSSMAgent     Amazon SSM Agent
```

and also i checked the agent status in the
[image]
[image]

But now when i try to check for this managed instance in my aws console i dont see.

I am checking in the fleet manager. i see its empty

[image]